# If $N$ is not a power of a prime, why does 1 have -1 as a root modulo $N$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factoring, prime-factorization

> If integer $N$ is not a power of a prime, it is the product of two coprime
>   integer numbers greater than 1. As a consequence of the Chinese remainder
>   theorem, the number 1 has at least four distinct roots modulo $N$, two
>   of them being $1$ and $-1$. (From [Wikipedia: Shor's_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm#Procedure))

Can anyone explain why does 1 have -1 as a root modulo $N$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$-1$ is always a *square* root of $1$, since $(-1)(-1)=1$.  It's also a fourth root, sixth root, eight root, etc., for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. Note that the congruence $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{6}$ has only two solutions. The same is true for all numbers of the form $2p^k$, where $p$ is an odd prime and $k\ge 1$.

Comment: In an earlier paragraph, the Wikipedia entry specifies $N$ as *odd*.  The OP neglected to copy that portion.

Comment: If OP changes the statement, and I find out about it, I will delete.